# ZMQSocketException: Failed to connect the ZMQ: Protocol not supported

Tags: php, sockets, yii2, zeromq

I am having problems with connecting my sockets

I am using Rachet and the guide provided by them http://socketo.me/docs/push for a simple push and pull sockets , but upon trying to connect my push socket I am given ZMQSocketException: Failed to connect the ZMQ: Protocol not supported

this is my controller code where i try to connect the socket

```php
$fileData = $request->post('File');
$context = new ZMQContext(); 
$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'pusher');
$socket->connect("tcp:://localhost:5555"); 
$socket->send(json_encode($fileData));
```

here is my pull socket where I start my server awaiting messages to be received,

```php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../handlers/FileHandler.php';

$loop    = Factory::create();
$handler = new FileHandler();

$context = new Context($loop);
$pull    = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');
$pull->on('message', [$handler, 'onFileDataSubmit']);

$webSock   = new React\Socket\Server('127.0.0.1:8080', $loop);
$webServer = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new 
WampServer($handler))), 8080);

$webServer->run();
```

Comment: Do you have https://zeromq.org/ installed, running, and listening on port 5555?

Comment: Yes, I have and have also enabled it in php.ini

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: No, I am using MacOS 10

Comment: Does the SOCKET_PULL work but the SOCKET_PUSH does not?

Comment: PUSH does not work, I failed to clarify error comes from this line
$socket->connect("tcp:://localhost:5555");  when I try to connect

Comment: Answered the question, there's two `::` in the line. You should only have one. Also you could try 127.0.0.1 if ZMQ is bound to 127.0.0.1 instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I think is caused by having two `::` in this line. Please use the following line which has only one.

```php
$socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
// OR
// $socket->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
```